# Why does session_start() create a blank file?

Tags: php, session

Let's start a session:

```
session_start();
```

A new file is created on `session_save_path()` folder, e.g. "sess_ovp3r00elb9q07jkb3kthcbhn5".

This file is a 0 bytes empty file.

I know I can remove it at the end of script this way:

```
if (session_status() == PHP_SESSION_ACTIVE AND !$_SESSION) @session_destroy();
```

But, why does PHP create this empty file?

Is it possible to change this behaviour and create the file only when a variable is set?

Thanks

**EDIT: Duplicate answers have no relation with my question.**

Comment: Why do you care? These files get cleaned up by the garbage collector. There's no reason to worry about them, and no reason to go mucking with the internals. Why are you starting sessions if you're not going to use them?

Comment: I am just curious. PHP is generating garbage with these empty files.